# Data section and text section in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I'm new to MIPS and I found that mostly we have to define a data section and a text section. I can understand that as it's just like to define a variable and to assign instructions. But why is writing ".data" and ".text" necessary? Is it possible to write code in MIPS without literally writing down ".data" and ".text"? For example, when I'm writing a program that only plays with registers, I don't even need to define anything in the data section now; why do I bother to write ".data"? And maybe I can neglect ".text" in this case as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to create a `.data` section if you're not using one.

Whether you need to explicitly create a `.text` section is assembler-dependent. For example, if you're using QtSPIM it seems to default to assembling into the `.text` section (but you still need to specify a global `main` label since QtSPIM's startup code contains a `jal main` instruction).

Comment: Do you know if it defaults to assemble into text section in MARS?

Comment: No, but that would be easy for you to test. Just load a source code file with no explicitly created `.text` section and see what happens.

Comment: I just tried a simple example and it seems like that MARS works okay without specifically declaring .text.